# Create UNC in Windows

Tags: windows, path, local, unc

I am using Windows 10 Home at home.

There is a folder called C:\LocalData in my computer.

I need to map it to \\AllData.

At work, we use an Access database with a front-end and a back-end database. The front-end looks for \\AllData\back-end.accdb.

I used to be able to take a copy of both files home, place the back-end at C:\LocalData and since my computer knew it was \AllData, the front-end worked without noticing it was a copy.

My hard drive failed and I had to reinstall everything on a new one. The reference I had created is gone.

Since I can't recreate the reference, I need to manually relink the back-end in the front-end when I work at home, and relink it again when I take it back to the office. It is time consuming.

I don't remember how I did it originally, but I believe it had something to do with IIS, the hosts file, or something like that.

I tried sharing the folder in Windows Explorer. That way I can get Windows to assign the UNC \\AllData to C:\LocalData, but is useless because Windows keeps asking for a user and password that never not work.

I did it in this computer, with this version of windows, and it was easy. I just don't remember how I did it.

Comment: Your description of what you may have done in the past is very confusing. Perhaps try putting it in shorter sentences. // You can create symbolic links to UNC paths, but it will still be network access. Please explain what your goal is.

Comment: Thanks. I rewrote it with shorter sentences and more detail. It was also showing only one backslash instead of two, making it more confusing.